# django views.py - display positiveinteger text value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a models class with a select list / positive integer field.

```
class AchievementDetails(models.Model, FillableModelWithLanguageVersion):
    ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT = 1
    COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 2
    PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 3
    PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT = 4
    SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT = 5
    OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE = 6

ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES = (
    (ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Academic Details')),
    (COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Commercial Achievement')),
    (PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Personal Achievement')),
    (PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Professional Achievement')),
    (SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT, _('Sporting Achievement')),
    (OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, _('Other Achievement Type')),
)

....
achievement_type = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES)
....
```

In my views.py I am trying to display the selected text of the achievement type. For example: Academic Achievement

Currently I can only display the selected numeric value. For example: 1

Here is the code that I have in my views.py:

```
def achievement_details(request):
    ....
    for ad in achievement_details:
        ad.achievement_type_as_text = ad.achievement_type
    ....
```

**What is the correct code to return the selected text of the ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

So, for my example, the syntax would be:

```
def achievement_details(request):
....
for ad in achievement_details:
    ad.achievement_type_as_text = ad.get_achievement_type_dispay()
....
```

I hope that this can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a list of tuples you want to use something like the following

```
ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES = (
    (ACADEMIC_ACHIEVEMENT, 'Academic Details'),
    (COMMERCIAL_ACHIEVEMENT, 'Commercial Achievement'),
    (PERSONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, 'Personal Achievement'),
    (PROFESSIONAL_ACHIEVEMENT, 'Professional Achievement'),
    (SPORTING_ACHIEVEMENT, 'Sporting Achievement'),
    (OTHER_ACHIEVEMENT_TYPE, 'Other Achievement Type'),
)

result = [item for item in ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES if item[0] == ad.achievement_type]

ad.achievement_type_as_text = result[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. if i place your code in the views.py. I get the error message: global name 'ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES' is not defined.
How do I import the ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES? Unsure how to import it from the models.py or even if I am doing this right.

Comment: You can place it in your models.py file and then if you need to use it elsewhere you can do the following: from models.py import ACHIEVEMENT_TYPES